# Running a YouTube API search query doesn't yield all expected results

Tags: api, youtube

I'm running this query - https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&order=date&type=video&q=scorerelief2021

But some videos that I would expect to appear in the results do not.  For example this one - https://youtu.be/iD2DCBDIHT8

It seems to meet the criteria, having the search term in the description...

Comment: It would help if you add the code snippet and question rather than posting a link which might be broken in the future. Please refer to standards for asking questions in Stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Actually there's no code snippet.  It's an API query which you can emulate here - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Comment: So if you run it in the emulator there and set the publishedBefore value to 2020-12-28T00:00:00Z then you don't pick up the video that I cited above, which you should...I have no idea why...

Comment: Maybe it's because the search term, on the video which is not being picked up, is not in the 'title' of the video but only in the description?  But my understand is that the API should search both, right?